# AVRO encode api crash when trying to encode a string

Tags: c++, boost, gdb, avro

I am new to programming and AVRO. So, please kindly bear with me.
I am trying to encode and decode few strings in AVRO format.
I have followed the same example as mentioned in the APACHE AVRO CPP page.
reference :- https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.10.2/api/cpp/html/index.html .

This is my JSON Schema.

```
 {
     "type": "record",
     "name": "cpx",
     "fields" : [
         {"name": "re", "type": "string"},
         {"name": "im", "type" : "string"}
     ]
 }
```

This is my generated header file.

```
namespace c {
struct cpx {
    std::string re;
    std::string im;
    cpx() :
        re(std::string()),
        im(std::string())
        { }
};

}
namespace avro {
template<> struct codec_traits<c::cpx> {
    static void encode(Encoder& e, const c::cpx& v) {
        avro::encode(e, v.re);
        avro::encode(e, v.im);
    }
    static void decode(Decoder& d, c::cpx& v) {
        if (avro::ResolvingDecoder *rd =
            dynamic_cast<avro::ResolvingDecoder *>(&d)) {
            const std::vector<size_t> fo = rd->fieldOrder();
            for (std::vector<size_t>::const_iterator it = fo.begin();
                it != fo.end(); ++it) {
                switch (*it) {
                case 0:
                    avro::decode(d, v.re);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    avro::decode(d, v.im);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            avro::decode(d, v.re);
            avro::decode(d, v.im);
        }
    }
};
```

}

This is my CPP source file.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "bla.hh"
#include "avro/Encoder.hh"
#include "avro/Decoder.hh"


 int main()
 {
     std::unique_ptr<avro::OutputStream> out = avro::memoryOutputStream();
     avro::EncoderPtr e = avro::binaryEncoder();
     e->init(*out);
     c::cpx c1;
     c1.re = "hello";
     c1.im = "thanks";
     avro::encode(*e, c1);

     std::unique_ptr<avro::InputStream> in = avro::memoryInputStream(*out);
     avro::DecoderPtr d = avro::binaryDecoder();
     d->init(*in);

     c::cpx c2;
     avro::decode(*d, c2);
     std::cout << '(' << c2.re << ", " << c2.im << ')' << std::endl;
     std::cout << "DECODED" << std::endl;
     return 0;
 }
```

this is how I compiled my binary

**g++ test.cpp -std=c++11 -lavrocpp**

And when I run this, I got a crash and this is my core dump.

[root@2-9 bin_kw]# gdb ./a.out /data/storage/corefiles/core.a.out

[root@2-9 bin_kw]# gdb

> ./a.out
> /data/storage/corefiles/core.a.out.30222.2-9.com.1658156296
> GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-115.el7 Copyright (C)
> 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc. License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3
> or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html This is free software: you
> are free to change and redistribute it. There is NO WARRANTY, to the
> extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for
> details. This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu". For bug
> reporting instructions, please see:
> http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/... Reading symbols from
> /root/Nightly_Suite_Workspace/MS/CU_CP/bin_kw/a.out...(no debugging
> symbols found)...done. [New LWP 30222] [Thread debugging using
> libthread_db enabled] Using host libthread_db library
> "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1". Core was generated by `./a.out'. Program

> terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.

> #0  __memcpy_ssse3_back () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3-back.S:896 896
> movaps  0x37(%rsi), %xmm5 warning: File
> "/usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.21-gdb.py" auto-loading has been
> declined by your `auto-load safe-path' set to
> "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load:/usr/bin/mono-gdb.py". To enable
> execution of this file add
> add-auto-load-safe-path /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.21-gdb.py line to your configuration
> file "/root/.gdbinit". To completely disable this security protection
> add
> set auto-load safe-path / line to your configuration file "/root/.gdbinit". For more information about this security protection
> see the "Auto-loading safe path" section in the GDB manual.  E.g., run
> from the shell:
> info "(gdb)Auto-loading safe path" Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install
> boost-filesystem-1.53.0-28.el7.x86_64
> boost-iostreams-1.53.0-28.el7.x86_64
> boost-program-options-1.53.0-28.el7.x86_64
> boost-regex-1.53.0-28.el7.x86_64 boost-system-1.53.0-28.el7.x86_64
> bzip2-libs-1.0.6-13.el7.x86_64 libicu-50.2-3.el7.x86_64

(gdb) bt

> #0  __memcpy_ssse3_back () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3-back.S:896
> #1  0x00007f28e9dad9e1 in avro::BinaryEncoder::encodeString(std::string const&) () from
> /usr/local/lib/libavrocpp.so.1.11.0
> #2  0x0000000000401778 in avro::codec_traits<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
> std::char_traits, std::allocator >
>
> > ::encode(avro::Encoder&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&) ()
> > #3  0x0000000000401a6e in void avro::encode<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits,
> > std::allocator > >(avro::Encoder&,
> > std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits,
> > std::allocator > const&) ()
> > #4  0x0000000000401830 in avro::codec_traits<c::cpx>::encode(avro::Encoder&, c::cpx const&) ()
> > #5  0x0000000000401ddc in void avro::encode<c::cpx>(avro::Encoder&, c::cpx const&) ()
> > #6  0x00000000004014ac in main ()**

I tried to figure it out , but I couldn't get any clue.
Please help me, Thanks in Advance.
[This is the page I was referring to.](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.10.2/api/cpp/html/index.html)

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to use the schema. Is it relevant to the question?

Comment: The schema has been converted to bla.hh

Answer (score 0):

I installed the library from the link and built the code, mostly unmodified:

```
#include <string>
//#include "bla.hh"
#include "api/Compiler.hh"
#include "api/DataFile.hh"
#include "api/Decoder.hh"
#include "api/Encoder.hh"
#include "api/Generic.hh"
#include "api/Stream.hh"

namespace c {
    struct cpx {
        std::string re;
        std::string im;
        cpx() :
            re(std::string()),
            im(std::string())
        { }
    };
}

namespace avro {
template<>
struct codec_traits<c::cpx>
{
    static void encode(Encoder& e, const c::cpx& v)
    {
        avro::encode(e, v.re);
        avro::encode(e, v.im);
    }
    static void decode(Decoder& d, c::cpx& v)
    {
        if(avro::ResolvingDecoder* rd =
               dynamic_cast<avro::ResolvingDecoder*>(&d))
        {
            const std::vector<size_t> fo = rd->fieldOrder();
            for(std::vector<size_t>::const_iterator it = fo.begin();
                it != fo.end();
                ++it)
            {
                switch(*it)
                {
                case 0: avro::decode(d, v.re); break;
                case 1: avro::decode(d, v.im); break;
                default: break;
                }
            }
        } else
        {
            avro::decode(d, v.re);
            avro::decode(d, v.im);
        }
    }
};
} // namespace avro

#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<avro::OutputStream> out =
        avro::memoryOutputStream();
    avro::EncoderPtr e = avro::binaryEncoder();
    e->init(*out);
    c::cpx c1;
    c1.re = "hello";
    c1.im = "thanks";
    avro::encode(*e, c1);

    std::unique_ptr<avro::InputStream> in =
        avro::memoryInputStream(*out);
    avro::DecoderPtr d = avro::binaryDecoder();
    d->init(*in);

    c::cpx c2;
    avro::decode(*d, c2);
    std::cout << '(' << c2.re << ", " << c2.im << ')' << std::endl;
    std::cout << "DECODED" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It runs seemingly fine and prints

```
(hello, thanks)
DECODED
```

I even enabled -fsanitize=address,undefined for the entire project (including inside avro/lang/c++/CMakeLists.txt) and it still runs cleanly.

You might try by linking statically:

```
g++ test.cpp -std=c++11 -lavrocpp_s
```

If that **does** work then in all likelihood, when building you're finding a different version of avrocpp than is installed and found at runtime. You can also verify this by using

```
ldd a.out
```

and see what shared library is resolved at runtime for `libavrocpp.so`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sehe. But even linking the library statically didn't help me! I am not sure what to do next. Could you please suggest?

Comment: Are  you using conan? I am seeing trouble when I tried to use conan for things. Compare https://github.com/sehe/repro-so/tree/q73024824 to https://github.com/sehe/repro-so/tree/q73024824-conan